# IDA code highlight?

Tags: ida

Is there a way (native or through plugin) to configure a code highlight scheme in IDA disasm?

I'm looking for something like what we have in ollydbg or x64dbg, some code highlight to make easy on the eyes to find jumps, calls, etc. This seems to be such a good missing feature in IDA as I just can't find it anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Does being able to apply colors to lines of code inside of the control flow graphs count? if so, check this out for some ideas: https://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/01/using-idapython-to-make-your-life-easier-part-4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is IDASkins:
https://github.com/zyantific/IDASkins
and this theme: 
https://github.com/eugeii/ida-consonance

For more plugins, go to: https://github.com/onethawt/idaplugins-list

Comment: Big ups on sharing that list of plugins! Just what I've been looking for.

Comment: Hey! No problem :) I'm glad you found it useful

Comment: Thanks I didn't test yet but reading the links you shared it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem! :-)